# Group texts based on their similarity to LDA topics/feature clusters

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification, cluster-analysis

I am working on a database containing forum threads content (first post + replies). I would like to group/clusterize these documents based on the topics of the first posts.

I computed LDA/LSI topics and tried K-means clusterizing, but I can't find documentation on how to get the related text documents from the cluster. I only get the main features of each cluster, but I want the whole documents or like some ID associated to it from each cluster.

I also tried a classifier and a recommender with known machine learning algorithms, but their results are not really useful. I also tried computing similarity using word2vec and doc2vec, the results are not very precise either.

So to sum up, I would like to group text documents based on their similar features/topics, without loosing a link to their content (like an ID). I have also more advanced methods in mind but I would like this to work first. The goal is to group posts from users that have the same issues using software and maybe the same reasons for these issues.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [lda](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lda) library in Python to create the LDA representation of documents as in:

```
import lda
model = lda.LDA(n_topics=20, n_iter=1500, random_state=1)
model.fit(X)
lda_representation = model.doc_topic_
```

assuming X is you documents matrix with size **n_doc x n_vocab** and your lda representation is of size **n_doc x n_topics**.

Then you cluster lda_representations with [k-means algorithm from sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html):

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(lda_representation)
clusters = kmeans.labels_
```

where clusters is of size **n_docs x 1** and is your cluster assignment for each document as for example **clusters[0]** is a number between **0** to **n_clusters - 1**
which tells you that document_0 belongs to cluster n.

Comment: thanks seems to be what I am looking for, i'm going to try it. However I use gensim to compute LDA but I should be able to adapt your code to it

Comment: I made it work but I have len(clusters) = len(vocab).
So I am getting where each term belongs instead of where each document belongs (clusters[0] is the cluster number of term_0 instead of document_0). Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: print lda_presentation.shape to make sure you're feeding the right representation to kmeans. lda_presentation.shape[0] should be the size of your documents.